# How to get an array of coordinates that make up a circle in canvas?

Tags: arrays, html, html5-canvas, coordinates, geometry

So, if this is the code I'm using to draw a circle on my canvas:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.stroke();
```

... how could I get an array of coordinates of the points that make up this circle so I can save them in a database and load on canvas later using the context.moveTo() and context.lineTo() methods to connect the dots, drawing the same circle?

I guess I'm asking if it's possible to draw this kind of circle using not .arc() method but by connecting dots with lines, if I only know my center coordinates and circle radius (and of course the width of the line and color). This should enable me to save each dot coordinates in an array as I loop through.

Comment: Please specify in your tags - what "canvas" is that (from what library)? Most canvases I have come across feature a built-in way to draw complete circles/ellipses. Also: When connecting *corner points* with *straight lines*, you will never get a real circle. But to get close to it (as close as you like), you will need to specify the frequency (distance angle) of the dots on the circle's circumference.

Answer (score 6):

@Octopus is on the right track:

```
var centerX=100;
var centerY=100;
var radius=40;

// an array to save your points
var points=[];

for(var degree=0;degree<360;degree++){
    var radians = degree * Math.PI/180;
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians);
    points.push({x:x,y:y});
}
```

Then you can draw the circle using the point objects in the points array:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle="skyblue";
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle="lightgray";
ctx.lineWidth=3;
ctx.stroke()
```

**A suggestion, however...**

Instead of saving all the points in the database, just save the centerX/Y and radius in the database.

Then you can use this same math to create the points and draw the circle.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering saving radius+center coordinates in the database, however since I'm already using a table to save coordinates for free hand drawing and straight lines, I figured I would use the same table for circle drawing. I'm using AJAX requests to get back the data from the table in a form of array. So it's just because of that basically.

Comment: @markE could you please provide a link to the live demo of the updated code??

Comment: Yes, but the code presented above is almost all of the code necessary to make the drawing "live".  Anyway, here's the live version:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/85aPs/  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the formula for a circle which is:

```
radius*radius = (x-centerX)*(x-centerX) + (y-centerY)*(y-centerY)
```

Or if you want to generate *n* points do something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    x[i] = centerX + radius* Math.cos( (i*2*Math.PI)/n );
    y[i] = centerY + radius*-Math.sin( (i*2*Math.PI)/n );
}
```